# Where can I download jvm files for oracle on ubuntu

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, java

I want to install Java packages for oracle, and I found following files in the internet.

```
@?/javavm/install/initjvm.sql;
@?/xdk/admin/initxml.sql;
@?/xdk/admin/xmlja.sql;
@?/rdbms/admin/catjava.sql;
@?/rdbms/admin/catexf.sql;
```

But I could find `javavm` folder anywhere on my computer. How can I get it?

Comment: Those files should be in your `$ORACLE_HOME`. What Oracle database (&version) did you install already?

Comment: @Mat i installed oracle XE 11.2